# iOS CloudKit Fetching assets stop working

Tags: ios, xcode, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-environments

I am working on application in which I stored the images in a cloud kit public database.I fetch the images from the cloud kit using perform query. Suddenly it stops working. It shows me error:

```
Internal Error" (1/1000); "Encountered an error fetching records
```

I am already login into cloud kit in my iOS device. I am using Sandbox environment.

Now Query operation did complete never called. It is one into infinite wait?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue now. Did you ever find a solution?